# "successfully opened CUDA library" not showing

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am following a tutorial at https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-jupyter-aws.

I would like to connect to a (CUDA compatible) GPU to do computations in a Jupyter notebook.  Following the tutorial linked above, I have chosen (AWS EC2) deep learning AMI ubuntu, p2.xlarge, and the instance is running.

Once I log into the cloud server using the IP address of the p2.xlarge instance, I import keras as they do in the tutorial.  However, instead of "Using TensorFlow backend....successfully opened CUDA library" being returned in the IPython shell, I get:

```
In [1]: import keras

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

Using TensorFlow backend.

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:962: UserWarning: Duplicate key in file "/home/ubuntu/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc", line #2
  (fname, cnt))

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:962: UserWarning: Duplicate key in file "/home/ubuntu/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc", line #3
  (fname, cnt))
```

Could someone tell me what's going wrong?  Also, if I get it working, will this instance work even for computations not involving keras (e.g., for reducing the dimension of data for a t-SNE)?

Comment: These are all warnings, no errors. You can fix the duplicate setting in `matplotlibrc` but the first warning comes from a libraries and should usually be fix by its developers in a new version.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say "successfully opened CUDA library" in the shell, as it does in the tutorial.  Is that okay?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running toy example and check with `nvidia-smi` if the gpu is used

Comment: nvidia-smi is showing Memory-Usage and GPU-Util both at 0, and no running processes.  But I can't figure out why.  I still think it's related to the fact that "successfully opened CUDA library" never appeared when importing keras.  Any ideas?  Thank you.